# How to define variables in Vue router to be used inside components?

Tags: html, css, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I have a navbar on top and a `<router-view>` right below it (as seen in `App.vue`). I want the title inside the navbar to change depending on the route/view I am on. Since my views in the `<router-view>` do not contain the title itself, I need to define them somewhere. An example for the scenario could be when reaching the route `/login`, the title in the navbar changes to "Login".
How do I achieve this?

When searching for a solution, I came across a lot of page title questions. I am not talking about the `document.title` assignment, however, that could be a solution, but not a perfect one. What if I wanted the title to be something else than the document title..

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <Menu :isActive="isMenuActive" />
  <Navbar @toggle:hamburger="onHamburgerToggle($event)" />
  <router-view />
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue router allows you to attach any information you want to any route using [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      meta: { title: "FOO" }
    }      
  ]
})
```

You can access the information for currently active route in any component using `$route` [variable](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object)

```js
const child = Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
    Child component ("{{ $route.meta.title }}")
  </div>
  `
})

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',  
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'route1',
      path: '/route1',
      component: child,
      meta: { title: 'Hello from route 1!'}
    },    
    {
      name: 'route2',
      path: '/route2',
      component: child,
      meta: { title: 'Hello from route 2!'}
    },    
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/route1">Route 1</router-link>
  <router-link to="/route2">Route 2</router-link>
  
  <h4> Current route: {{ $route.meta.title }} </h4>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every component can access the `$route` object, so you could use that directly in your template.  Or you can access that object in the script and do something with it.

Imagine your routes have the `name` property:

*router/index.js*

```js
routes: [
  { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
  { path: '/foo', name: 'foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', name: 'bar', component: Bar }
]
```

You could show that name in the template with no script necessary:

*Navbar.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>Title: {{ $route.name }}</div>
</template>
```

<sup>(`meta` is also a good idea here as explained in **@MichalLevý**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66506069/2185093).)</sup>

Or you could access the route object in the script and create a title however you want.

*Navbar.vue* (Composition API)

```html
<template>
  <div>Title: {{ title }}</div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    const title = ref('My title ' /* Do something with `route` */);
    return { title }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I found out its a good idea to do:
`const title = computed(() => route.meta.title || 'default title');` - this way it updates whenever the title changes. Maybe it is possible to set the default value in router, but then you have to assign it to every route..

Comment: It's nice to provide that fallback for routes with no `meta`.  If you're just using `meta`, you don't need to use a computed or any script.  You could put that straight in the template:  `{{ $route.meta.title || 'default title' }}`

Comment: You are right. No need for the extra step. In my project I have two headers depending on the title, it changes the placement :)

Comment: This is what Michal suggested, so I suggest to accept his answer instead if you don't need to make any modifications in the component